# How to send a realtime notification to specific user in Blazor wasm client from ASP.NET Core background service using SignalR in .NET 8

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, signalr, blazor-webassembly

I'm new to SignalR and learning it and practicing it for the first time. I'm trying to send real time notification to specific `User` in my Blazor WASM app from a `BackgroundService` in ASP.NET Core Web API using SignalR in .NET 8 as per the following code.

Client-side:

```cs
private HubConnection? _hubConnection;
private readonly List<string> _notifications = new();

[Inject] IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider { get; set; }

[Inject] IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

[CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
    var user = authState.User;

    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                        .WithUrl($"{Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiBaseAddress")}notifications",
                        options =>
                        {
                            options.AccessTokenProvider = async () =>
                            {
                                var accessTokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
                                accessTokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token);
                                return token.Value;
                            };
                        })
                        .Build();

        _hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveNotification", notification =>
        {
            _notifications.Add(notification);

            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        });

        await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
}
```

I'm sending the auth token along with the connection.

Server-side:

`Hub`:

```cs
[Authorize]
public class NotificationsHub : Hub<INotificationClient>
{
}

public interface INotificationClient
{
    Task ReceiveNotification(string message);
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```cs
...
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
...
app.MapHub<NotificationsHub>("notifications");
```

`BackgroundService`:

```cs
public class InventoryNotifier(
    IHubContext<NotificationsHub, INotificationClient> hubContext,
    ILogger<InventoryNotifier> logger) : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            await hubContext.Clients
                .All
                .ReceiveNotification($"InventoryNotifier is starting... {DateTime.Now}");
        }

        stoppingToken.Register(() => logger.LogWarning($"{nameof(InventoryNotifier)} is stopping due to host shut down."));
    }
}
```

The above setup works fine and I receive notifications in my Blazor wasm client app. However I'm sending messages to `Clients.All` from background service.

```cs
await hubContext.Clients
                .All // <--- This sends for All Client.
                .ReceiveNotification($"InventoryNotifier is starting... {DateTime.Now}");
```

When I tried to send to specific `User`, I noticed that `Clients.User()` exists and that needs an `userId`.

How can I get the user id inside background service? After some research I noticed that I can use `IUserIdProvider` and call `GetUserId()` method from that as shown below.

```cs
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

/// <summary>
/// A provider abstraction for configuring the "User ID" for a connection.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks><see cref="IUserIdProvider"/> is used by <see cref="IHubClients{T}.User(string)"/> to invoke connections associated with a user.</remarks>
public interface IUserIdProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the user ID for the specified connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection">The connection to get the user ID for.</param>
    /// <returns>The user ID for the specified connection.</returns>
    string? GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection);
}
```

But again this requires `HubConnectionContext`. And now I'm not sure how to get `HubConnectionContext` inside `BackgroundService`.

The final idea I had in my mind is to have something like this:

```cs
public class InventoryNotifier(
    IHubContext<NotificationsHub, INotificationClient> hubContext,
    IUserIdProvider userIdProvider,
    ILogger<InventoryNotifier> logger) : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested && await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            await hubContext.Clients
                .User(userIdProvider.GetUserId()) // <---- Not sure how to get HubConnectionContext here
                //.All
                .ReceiveNotification($"InventoryNotifier is starting... {DateTime.Now}");
        }

        stoppingToken.Register(() => logger.LogWarning($"{nameof(InventoryNotifier)} is stopping due to host shut down."));
    }
}
```

Please can anyone assist me on this? Is this the right way? Or am I complicating it?

Comment: override the on connect method collect the userid and put the user into a group that is either the userid or a hash or the userid. Then you can use the group method to send to a group and the user should be the only one in it.

Comment: inside the onconnect override how to persist and get that id from backgroundservice? Any code sample you can share to help me in this?

Comment: Somewhere along the way your background service must now the userid of the request. This maybe from the originating Get or Post for example. This has to be attached to what you are doing in the background service. Take a look at this if it suites ill make it an answer. https://github.com/BrianLParker/Blazor8WithRolesAndSignalR

Comment: Thank you for your patience and support.. Will check and get back asap